# Using SpEL with enumeration restricted attribute in Spring context XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd-validation, spring-el

I'm configuring CXF conduit using Spring context and I'd like to be able to externalize one of the properties (client's `Connection` attribute) which is restricted by the schema as enumeration.

```
<http-conf:conduit name="...">  
  <http-conf:client  
    ConetntType="..."
    Connection="${key.of.my.externalized.property}"
  />
  ...
</http-conf:conduit>
```

The problem is that at boot time SAX parser will, of course, not allow it.
Is there a way I could avoid hard-coding `Connection` attribute value and inject it using property placeholder apart from removing said schema?